# how to combine two different array of objects into one new array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects with same news_ids but different properties, I am just wondering how to combine them and get a new array of objects?

For example:

```
let arr1 = [{
    news_id: 1,
    title: "title1"
  },
  {
    news_id: 2,
    title: "title2"
  },
  {
    news_id: 3,
    title: "title3"
  },
  {
    news_id: 4,
    title: "title4"
  },
]

let arr2 = [{
    news_id: 3,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    news_id: 4,
    count: 4
  }
]
```

And I would like to get:

```
[
  {news_id: 1, title: "title1", count: 0},
  {news_id: 2, title: "title2", count: 0},
  {news_id: 3, title: "title3", count: 3},
  {news_id: 4, title: "title4", count: 4}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to use nested loops but it is returning the elements only same ids.

Comment: @hackrack, pls mark the answer as an accepted solution if it helped you achieve what you were looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `forEach` and `filter` as below:

```
arr1.forEach(i => i.count = (arr2.find(j => j.news_id == i.news_id) || { count: 0 }).count)
```

Try it below.

```js
let arr1 = [{
    news_id: 1,
    title: "title1"
  },
  {
    news_id: 2,
    title: "title2"
  },
  {
    news_id: 3,
    title: "title3"
  },
  {
    news_id: 4,
    title: "title4"
  },
]

let arr2 = [{
    news_id: 3,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    news_id: 4,
    count: 4
  }
]

arr1.forEach(i => i.count = (arr2.find(j => j.news_id == i.news_id) || { count: 0 }).count);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done as follows. Also this is generic and will concat all properties for same news_id, not just count and title.

```
let arr1 = [
              {news_id: 1, title: "title1"},
              {news_id: 2, title: "title2"},
              {news_id: 3, title: "title3"},
              {news_id: 4, title: "title4"},
           ]


let arr2 = [
             {news_id: 3, count: 3},
             {news_id: 4, count: 4}
           ]

let result = Object.values(([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, d) => (acc[d.news_id] = { count:0, ...acc[d.news_id], ...d }, acc) ,{})))
```

Comment: Yes, @NickParsons I intentionally did generic approach so that other properties can also be taken care of. Though I did add "count" as well there to be more specific.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your case to get the desired result.I recommend you should try old school [JS forEach() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp).

**And here is the example done check it on [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pLou7cxt/2/)**

```
let arr1 = [{
    news_id: 1,
    title: "title1"
  },
  {
    news_id: 2,
    title: "title2"
  },
  {
    news_id: 3,
    title: "title3"
  },
  {
    news_id: 4,
    title: "title4"
  }
]

let arr2 = [
    {
    news_id: 3,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    news_id: 4,
    count: 4
  }
]


arr1.forEach(function (e,i) {
    var flag = false;
  arr2.forEach(function (obj, j) {
        if (e.news_id === obj.news_id) {
            e.count = obj.count;
      flag = true;
        }
    });
  if(!flag){
    e.count = 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution. I simply iterate `arr1` and add the `count` from the matching `arr2` item, if any.

```
for (item of arr1) {
    let arr2item = arr2.find(item2 => item2.news_id === item.news_id);
  item['count'] = arr2item ? arr2item.count : 0;
};
```

[@Nitish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52833333/127826) looks good, but the intention is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting all given data and the counts. Then render the final result.

```js
var array1 = [{ news_id: 1, title: "title1" }, { news_id: 2, title: "title2" }, { news_id: 3, title: "title3" }, { news_id: 4, title: "title4" }],
    array2 = [{ news_id: 3, count: 3 }, { news_id: 4, count: 4 }],
    result = Array.from(
        array2
            .reduce(
                (m, { news_id, count }) => (m.get(news_id).count += count, m),
                array1.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.news_id, Object.assign({}, o, { count: 0 })), new Map)
            )
            .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```